# Why does VSCode not complain my #include when my path is not correct ( not enough ../ in path)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, path, include

I have some C++ - code where in a cpp-file I include a header-file like that:

```
#include "../../../c/win/c_pp/include/abc.h"
```

Now my file abc.h is actually in a folder that should be addressed like this ( with an additional  **../** ) :

```
#include "../../../../c/win/c_pp/include/abc.h"
```

The strange thing is:

There is no file *abc.h* in *../../../c/win/c_pp/include/* but VSCode does not complain and compiles fine. I can use either way. **Why is that that the case?**

Comment: Please post a [mcve], including the commands you use to compile the project - what flags, include paths in particular, are you passing to the compiler?

Comment: Just guessing, but probably your source file is in a sub-directory of your project location and the project location is set as one of the default include paths.

Comment: Remember that relative paths for `#include` are relative from the *source* file location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple possibilities:

First:

Your compiler gets additional arguments in the form of -I PATH or /I PATH.

-I .. would add .. to the given include path so transforming

```
#include "../../../c/win/c_pp/include/abc.h"
```

to

```
#include "../../../../c/win/c_pp/include/abc.h"
```

Therefore correctly accessing the correct file.

Second:

Your seem to use a mingw or similar toolchain on windows.
If the correct path of "abc.h" in your filesystem is:
"C:\win\c_pp\include\abc.h"

Prefixing this path with ".." (aka parent directory) does not change that.

So "../../../c/win/c_pp/include/abc.h" is the same as "../../../../c/win/c_pp/include/abc.h"

as "/c" or C: has no parent directory.

```
glaure@Harr MSYS /c
$ cd /c/           
                   
glaure@Harr MSYS /c
$ cd ..            
                   
glaure@Harr MSYS / 
$ cd ..            
                   
glaure@Harr MSYS / 
$
```

I hope that helps.

Bye Gunther